# Is there a way to install Samba packages offline for Fedora 14?

Tags: linux, fedora, fedora-14

need to install samba packages **offline** to enable sharing of my fedora 14 folders to windows system. is there a place/way to get the offline installation file? ThaNKS!

Comment: Fedora 14 has been end-of-life for a year now. Better upgrade (or install the latest version). If updating yearly is a chore, consider CentOS.

Comment: What do you mean by the offline installation file? You can download an rpm package and install that if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Fedora Archive Repository

```
http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/14/
```

Fedora 14 Samaba RPM Package

```
http://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/14/x86_64/
```

Search for samba in the above page.